# Python: How to use named variables from one function in other functions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, global-variables

I'm a newbie programmer trying to make a program, using Python 3.3.2, that has a `main()` function which calls `function1()`, then loops `function2()` and `function3()`.

My code generally looks like this:

```
def function1():
    print("hello")

def function2():
    name = input("Enter name: ")

def function3():
    print(name)

def main():
    function1()
    while True:
        funtion2()
        function3()
        if name == "":
            break

main()
```

Currently, I get the following error when I run the program and enter a name:

```
NameError: global name 'name' is not defined
```

I understand that this is because `name` is only defined within `function2()`. How do I make it so that `name` is defined as a 'global name', or somehow be able to use it within `function3()` and `main()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to define  it a global variable, return it instead:

```
def function2():
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    return name

def function3():
    print(function2())
```

---

If you want to use variables defined in function to be available across all functions then use a class:

```
class A(object):

   def function1(self):
       print("hello")

   def function2(self):
       self.name = input("Enter name: ")

   def function3():
       print(self.name)

   def main(self):  
       self.function1()
       while True:
          funtion2()
          function3()
          if not self.name:
              break

A().main()
```

Comment: I tried this but now it returns this error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\School\ITEC 1150-02\Address book group assignment\TEAMLAB2.py", line 43, in <module>
    A().main()
  File "I:\School\ITEC 1150-02\Address book group assignment\TEAMLAB2.py", line 37, in main
    function2()
NameError: global name 'function2()' is not defined`

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work; used `self.function2()` instead of just `function2()`. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Define the variable outside of your functions, and then declare it first as global inside with the `global` keyword. Although, this is almost always a bad idea because of all of the horrendous bugs you'll end up creating with global state.